# anyone tried Leap Motion with Unity? we can't grab objects in the Demo Pack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

We've setup the leap motion, got it to successfully run in Standard Unity by moving the DLLs around per instructions, and can successfully track hand positions when running the scenes in this demo. But we cannot grab objects in any scene. We have only gotten the Boxing and Flying scenes to work, because those in fact requires no gestures, simply pushing outwards knocks the bag around, or just detects relative positions of hands to cause flight. But the actual grab action we cannot get to execute, in Unity only. The Airspace apps (orientation + freeform) work fine, and the Visualizer works fine.

See this video short video of us trying http://youtu.be/9kTXCEwUhoc The documentation for the Boxing, ATVDriving, and Weapons all just say to grab when colliding, but we've tried many times and cannot get it to execute even once. The rings should turn red like exactly here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA7a6foNlHo&t=1m8s but they never do, always staying blue no matter what we do.

Any idea what's wrong?

Demo Pack Documentation: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/skeletal/csharp/devguide/Unity_Demo_Pack.html

GitHub project: https://github.com/GameMakersUnion/LeapTest (already has DLLs setup for Standard -free- Unity)

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on the Leap Motion forum; thought I'd copy it here:

Are you trying to grab objects in general or are you trying to get the demo pack to work?

I don't really know why the demo pack doesn't work as I don't know very much about it, but if you're trying to make an app to grab objects you might check out our v2 tracking and skeletal assets.

developer.leapmotion.com // 
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/177703

There's a few demos in our gallery that show grabbing, specifically the RagdollThrower example.

Also, next week we'll be updating the skeletal unity assets with more powerful grabbing.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I thought it might be of interest.

(Source: https://community.leapmotion.com/t/anyone-here-tried-the-unity-demo-pack-we-cant-grab-objects-in-it/1415)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to look for the Physics model for Hand Pinching something like that. but the word pinch is the trick.
You can add the pinching to your hand contoller or sandbox, then the object should have Rigidbody to be grabable.

Please contact if you want to share info about leap and C#